# Нужна помощь с пунктуацией и стилистикой. Спасибо!

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Российской Федерации нужны люди, личности, способные реализовывать реформы последних 25 лет на различных уровнях власти. Каждый должен обладать прорывным характером, волей, достаточной для того, чтобы повести за собой миллионы людей. Должен присутствовать талант, который позволит ежедневно работать на благо своей страны. Требуется высочайшей степени сосредоточенность, внимательность и отдача.

Comment: Грамматических ошибок нет, но текст... мама не горюй. Неужто еще не все реформы реализовали?! Пропал калабуховский дом, сказал профессор Преображенский.

Comment: @Niemand, а про грамматические и не спрашивают. ))) Явных стилистических тоже, кстати, нет. Что же касается калабуховского дома, то это вообще не по теме. Вы ж даже не знаете, что это за текст и с какой целью он написан.

Comment: Ну, примерно-то вижу. "Повести миллионы людей", "талант на благо своей страны", "высочайшей степени отдача", "беспощаден к врагам рейха"...

"Калабуховский дом", имхо, очень даже по теме.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Comment: *Ну, примерно-то вижу. "Повести миллионы людей", "талант на благо своей страны", "высочайшей степени отдача", "беспощаден к врагам рейха"... "Калабуховский дом", имхо, очень даже по теме.* - у Вас странный взгляд на Булгакова. Глазами Швондера. А сейчас с любого экрана именно таким языком и изъясняются, если не про Донбасс.  Кстати, про "врагов Рейха" и проч. - выдумка гр. Семёнова. Подобные обороты (с заменой Рейха на "дело Сталина") и вообще язык был присущ более характеристике на члена КПСС, а не НСДАП. Многие так и понимали. Немцы же трибуну и рабочие документы не путали.

Comment: Короче, остаюсь при своем мнении, что Вы Булгакова всуе вспомнили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От канцелярской тональности здесь полностью не избавиться, но улучшить можно. В глаза бросается несоответствие "человеческих" эпитетов с "бесчеловечно-бюрократическими", а также смысловые неувязки из ходячих штампов:

- "реализовывать реформы... на уровнях власти" нельзя: на этих уровнях *управляют* проведением реформ, контролируют их ход и руководят людьми, которые, собственно говоря, их и *реализуют*; это из той же серии, что "Сталин выиграл войну" (= Троцкий выиграл Гражданскую, Хрущёв полетел в космос, Брежнев провёл Олимпиаду-80...);
- "прорывной" - эпитет из разговорной речи, он выпадает из общего стиля;
- "достаточность воли" наводит на странную мысль о её количественном измерении и сопоставлении с "миллионами" других единиц;
- "должен присутствовать талант" - где присутствовать?? В своё время справедливо критиковали элемент партийной риторики "есть мнение"; отсутствие таланта не позволяет кому-то работать ежедневно или работать на благо страны?
- от кого "требуется"?
- отдача - не "откат" ли это? (правильно "самоотдача")
- повторяющиеся близкие синонимы (сосредоточенность - внимательность, воля - прорывной характер)

Можно так попробовать:

> Российской Федерации на различных уровнях власти нужны талантливые
>   люди, личности, способные вести реформы, начатые 25 лет назад. От
>   каждого руководителя требуется настойчивый характер и понимание того,
>   что за ним стоят миллионы людей. Необходимо его искреннее желание
>   ежедневно работать на благо страны. От него требуется высочайшая
>   сосредоточенность и самоотдача в работе.

Comment: *отдача и самоотдача* - разные вещи, но обе здесь приемлемы. очень может быть, что имелось в виду именно самоотдача, но кто знает? внимательность и сосредоточенность - не синонимы, тем более не "близкие". Остальное у вас весьма субъективно. канцелярщины тут не вижу. Это другое. Это агитационный стиль передовиц середины XX века, к сожалению массово возвращающийся на полосы и экраны современных СМИ.

Answer (score 0):

А а чем нужна помощь-то?
Пунктуационных ошибок тут не обнаружил, говорить о стилистических не приходится, ибо явных недоразумений нет, а назначение текста неизвестно. есть некоторая пафосность, возможно излишняя, и этакое плакатное менторство, но отношение к этому определяется опять-таки контекстом, назначением текста. 
Для рекламной агитки вполне сойдет.